# Can there be a [nim-prologue] tag or similar for nim-lang's prologue webframework?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Prologue](https://github.com/planety/prologue) is one of the web-frameworks of the [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim_(programming_language)) programming language.

There are plenty of features and things one can ask questions about, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71545667/prologue-webframework-how-to-set-thread-local-variables-for-logging-when-comp/71545668#71545668) where I had a question about multi-threading, found the answer in collaboration with somebody and wanted to post the gained knowledge on SO, but I didn't have a tag to mark it appropriately.

As web frameworks generally tend to receive their own tags (Django ([Python](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info)), Spring ([Java](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info)), Jester ([Nim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nim-lang))), I would like to ask one for Prologue.

### Existing questions where the tag would be appropriate

[A question about how to set thread-local variables in the Prologue framework for the purposes of logging.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71545667/prologue-webframework-how-to-set-thread-local-variables-for-logging-when-comp)

[A question about how to access the HTTP request body within a prologue controller.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70524267/nim-how-to-access-raw-post-request-body-in-prologue-framework)

### Proposed tag wiki excerpt

Prologue is an open-source web framework created using the Nim programming language.

### Proposed tag wiki description

Prologue is an open-source web framework created using the Nim programming language. The framework provides extensive documentation to get started quickly and easily (https://planety.github.io/prologue/).

### Proposed name

Given that [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) is also a programming language however and there's a bunch of other Prolog-related tags already, I would suggest not naming it `prologue` as that might be confusing. `nim-prologue` or something similar would be more distinguishing.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the link! I've done a re-draft from what I could grasp of the linked question.

Comment: You must not plagiarise tag wiki descriptions: The original is here: https://github.com/planety/prologue

Comment: @RobertLongson Given that there's very little that makes sense to write there, I just scrapped the majority of the description and left the link to the docs in place.

Comment: @RobertLongson As the previous wording wasn't acceptable, I scrapped it down to the minimum as that's about the extent of wording that makes sense here and I'm not about to rewrite the github page, that would be a waste of effort for the reader and the writer.

Comment: The minimalized version that I put up in the last edit is not plagiarized.